# How do I create acts_as... and has_... for models in Rails? Like an Interface in Java

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails often has special keywords you can insert into a model that gives it special features. Some examples are [acts_as_taggable](http://taggable.rubyforge.org/files/README.html) or [has_attached_file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#models). How do I do that kind of Voodoo? I want to create a special option for subscriptions, and give models the ability to be subscribed to, for a RefineryCMS engine/extension. I don't know how to do that kind of Rails magic yet, and I didn't see a relevant Rails guide for it.

Comment: look at [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

Comment: @bjhaid Interesting. Is there a tutorial on that? I'm a little fuzzy on the difference between include and extend. Sometimes the Rails docs can be a littly dry, and not in a good way. Sometimes they don't even repeat important information once.

Answer (score 2):

Those are actually instance methods on the "Class" class. In Ruby, when you're inside a class definition block, `self` becomes that class. Since parentheses are optional in method invocations, you can make them look a lot like keyword declarations. So you can do

```
class Class
  def subscribable
    define_method :subscribe do
    ...
    end
  end
end

class Thing
 subscribable
end

Thing.new.subscribe
```

Comment: Ahh, neat. `define_method` seems key. What about the order classes are loaded? Is there some sort of configuration that you need to make sure your gem/module adds those features to Class before the target model is loaded?

Comment: Load order in Rails can get hairy. Typically if you're using a Gemfile and bundler gems will get auto-required before the project files. Otherwise you can put the code in an initializer file in your Rails directory.